# How can I add an array of numbers recursively under the condition that the sum will not be more than 20?

Tags: javascript, arrays, conditional-statements, sum

For example, there is an array:

```
[3, 8, 9, 2, 7, 5, 6, 5, 3, 11, 9, 17, 6, 5, 8, 4, 2, 7, 9, 12, 5, 16, 4]
```

Algorithm:

```
let arr = []

3 + 8 + 9 + 2 > 20 (do not sum)
3 + 8 + 9 = 20 (sum and push to arr)
next
9 + 2 + 7 + 5 > 20 (do not sum)
9 + 2 + 7 < 20 (sum and push to arr)
next
5 + 6 + 5 + 3 + 11 > 20 (do not sum)
5 + 6 + 5 + 3 < 20 (sum and push to arr)
...
```

The point is that there are files in the array with a certain weight in MB, and I need to merge them one by one, not exceeding 20MB, and make a new array from the merged ones.

I tried to do this with the following code, but I don't understand how to set my condition.

```
var sum = (array) => (array.length === 0) ? 0 : array[0] + sum(array.slice(1));
```

Comment: why is `3 + 8 + 9 > 20`? for me it's `20`, not greater.

Comment: yes the conditions are greater than or equal to, sorry, corrected

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could group by having a look to subset sum.

```js
const
    add = (a, b) => a + b,
    group = compare => (r, v, i) => {
        if (!i || compare(r.at(-1).reduce(add) + v)) r.push([v]);
        else r.at(-1).push(v);
        return r;
    },
    upTo = a => b => a <= b,
    lessThan = a => b => a < b,
    data = [3, 8, 9, 2, 7, 5, 6, 5, 3, 11, 9, 17, 6, 5, 8, 4, 2, 7, 9, 12, 5, 16, 4],
    result0 = data.reduce(group(lessThan(20)), []);
    result1 = data.reduce(group(upTo(20)), []);

console.log(result0);
console.log(result1);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: Thank you, everything looks correct, can it be adjusted so that the amount equal to 20 is also summed up?

Comment: @Alexey, please see edit.

Answer (score 0):

```js
function addValuesUntilSumLessThan20(arr) {
  let sum = 0;
  let resultArray = [];

  for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    if (sum + arr[i] <= 20) {
      sum += arr[i];
      resultArray.push(arr[i]);
    } else {
      break;
    }
  }

  return resultArray;
}

const inputArray = [3, 8, 9, 2, 7, 5, 6, 5, 3, 11, 9, 17, 6, 5, 8, 4, 2, 7, 9, 12, 5, 16, 4];
const result = addValuesUntilSumLessThan20(inputArray);

console.log(result); // Output: [3, 8, 9]
```

Comment: This only computes the *first* sum.

Answer (score 0):

After posing:

```
    const 
        data = [3, 8, 9, 2, 7, 5, 6, 5, 3, 11, 9, 17, 6, 5, 8, 4, 2, 7, 9, 12, 5, 16, 4],
        max = 20,
        expected = [[3, 8, 9], [2, 7, 5, 6], [5, 3, 11], [9], [17], [6, 5, 8], [4, 2, 7], [9], [12, 5], [16, 4]];
```

the `expected` array of arrays can be achieved through the `reduce(op, accumulator)` method of the `data` array by using as accumulator an object `{tmp: 0, frames: [[]]}` storing, with the expected `frames`, a further property `tmp` with the current length of last frame.

```
const
    push = (got, next) => { 

        if(got.tmp + next <= max) {
            got.tmp += next;
            got.frames[got.frames.length - 1]
               .push(next)
        } else {
            got.tmp = next;
            got.frames.push([next]);
        }

        return got
    },

    got = data.reduce(push, {tmp: 0, frames: [[]]});

assert.deepEqual(got.frames, expected)
```